# Why does document.querySelectorAll return an empty array in this context?

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

I have the following set of HTML elements

The unordered list with the class *options* is not displayed at page load:

I want do display it when the element `<div class="select-box">` is clicked. For this purpose I have:

I don't know why, bit `console.log(selectBox)` returns an empty array.

How can I fix this?

```js
/* Select Boxes */
function selectBoxToggle() {
  let selectBox = document.querySelectorAll('.select-box');
  console.log(selectBox);
  selectBox.forEach(function(item) {
    let options = item.querySelectorAll('.options');
    item.addEventListener("click", options.style.display = 'block');
    console.log(options);
  });
}

// On document load
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  selectBoxToggle();
});
```

```css
.select-box {
  position: relative;
}

.select-box .caret {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1px;
  top: 50%;
  color: #999;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.select-box .selected-value {
  height: 33px;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.select-box .options {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 0;
  top: 33px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="select-box">
  <div class="selected-value">Item 1</div>
  <ul class="options elevation-1">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
  <span class="material-icons caret">arrow_drop_down</span>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of `this.querySelectorAll('.options');` use `item.querySelectorAll('.options');`

Comment: If you use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), problems like this will throw errors.

Comment: But the problem is not the .options selector. Is that HTML really initially on the page and not added dynamically?

Comment: @GuyIncognito It is not added dynamically.

Comment: Then the problem is somewhere else that you're not showing, because that code works correctly (as far as the .select-box selector goes) as you can see if you run the code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to toggle a class instead

```js
/* Select Boxes */
const selectBoxToggle = () => {
  document.querySelector('.select-box').addEventListener("click",function() { // now you can use "this"
    this.querySelector('.options').classList.toggle("hide")
  });
}

// On document load
window.addEventListener("load",selectBoxToggle);
```

```css
.select-box {
  position: relative;
}

.select-box .caret {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1px;
  top: 50%;
  color: #999;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.select-box .selected-value {
  height: 33px;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.select-box .options {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 0;
  top: 33px;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.hide { display:none }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="select-box">
  <div class="selected-value">Items</div>
  <ul class="options elevation-1 hide">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
  <span class="material-icons caret">arrow_drop_down</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The fact that the code is part of a Svelte project might be the cause of this strange problem.

Comment: Ah, no idea about svelte

Answer (score 1):

Did you try putting li rather than options?